# Making sheet metal parts in Autodesk Fusion 360

Tags: cad, autodesk-inventor

I'm trying to do some sheet metal work in Autodesk Fusion 360 and it has proved frustrating in the extreme.  Maneuvering sketches and bodies to where I want them has proved extremely difficult.  I understand that Autodesk Inventor has far better support for sheet metal parts, which is great if I could afford Inventor.

What is a workflow for making sheet metal parts in Fusion 360?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This video about [Faux Sheet Metal](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/community/screencast/af415e28-f8ee-4b0d-b83b-b6076c2a941d) parts was incredibly helpful.

1. Start with a set of sketches that describe your sheet metal project.
2. Create patches based on those sketches.  Each patch can then be moved to it's proper location.
3. After the patches are where they should be, then they can be extruded into bodies with the appropriate thickness.

While this let's a user create parts that look like sheet metal parts, I believe there are significant differences between this process and a process that uses tools provided by Inventor or SolidWorks.

Comment: Is this the answer you were looking for your question? If so, please mark the answer as accepted. Also, why did you ask a question and answer it within the same minute?

Comment: @Wasabi I can't accept the answer for two days, so that part will have to wait.  I posted the question and answer so close together because I've had the question for a long time and this was the answer that satisfied it.  If there are better workflows, I'm happy to see them.  But, given the relative youth of Fusion360 and general lack examples on the internet, I don't anticipate seeing a better workflow till Autodesk adds real sheetmetal tools to Fusion360.